# How to install Apache Spark on Windows 10?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, installation, windows-10

I am trying to install `spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3` "Prebuilt for Apache Hadoop 3.3 and later" that I have downloaded from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html , On my Windows 10 machine.

But when I search for `winutils` the latest version I could find is `3.3.1` from here: https://github.com/kontext-tech/winutils. Also there are other `winutils` with lower versions on other Github pages.

As the latest version of Hadoop is `3.3.4` I don't know what to do? I even don't know should I install Hadoop before installing Spark? Or what Github page is the official page for `winutils`?

Comment: Hi! I was looking at a few weeks ago but didn't really completely follow up on this. I did find this interesting page (https://pivotalbi.com/build-your-own-winutils-for-spark/) which outlines how you can compile your own winutils on exactly the version you want. So you can just pull the apache-spark source code and compile winutils for the exact version you want :) Hope this helps!

Comment: @Koedlt: Thank you! I tried the `3.3.1` from the `kintext` github that I put the link within the question and it seems it works( as my SPark version is also the same. But Hadoop version was confusing for me).